# Prove that $C(n,0) + C(n+1,1) +\dots+ C(n+r,r) = C(n+r+1,r).$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am not even sure where to start with this question. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!
We are not allowed to use Mathematical Induction!

Comment: Unlikely that this hasn't been asked before: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871953/simplify-the-expression-binomn0-binomn11-binomn22-cdots-bin/, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658490/prove-that-sum-limits-k-0r-binomnkk-binomnr1r-using-combinatoric-a?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that $\binom{m}{i} = \binom{m}{m-i}$, so we can rewrite your equality into
$$
\binom{n}{n} + \binom{n+1}{n} + \cdots + \binom{n+r}{n} = \binom{n+r+1}{n+1}
$$
And here is my interpretation: you have $n+r+1$ numbered balls, and you want to pick $n+1$ of them. This can obviously be done in $\binom{n+r+1}{n+1}$ ways.

Now, let's divide this into cases by the highest number among the balls you pick. That number cannot be less than $n+1$, obviously. Now, how many ways are there to pick $n+1$ balls so that the largest number on any of them is $n+1$? Well, you obviously have to pick ball number $n+1$. After that, you have to pick $n$ balls from the $n$ balls with lower number. That can be done in $\binom nn$ ways.

If the highest number we pick is $n+2$, how many ways can that be done? We have to pick the $n+2$ ball, and after that we need to choose $n$ balls from the $n+1$ balls that are smaller than $n+2$. That can be done in $\binom{n+1}n$ ways. And so on. Adding all these contributions together, this eventually becomes $\binom{n}{n} + \binom{n+1}{n} + \cdots + \binom{n+r}{n}$.

These two ways count the same number of things, and therefore the result must be the same.

Comment: WOW! This was extremely helpful as well! Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Recall the fundamental property of [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient):
$$\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k}.$$
Let 
$$S_n(r):=\sum_{k=0}^r \binom{n+k}{k}$$ and try by induction with respect to $r$. Note that for the inductive step you should show that
$$S_n(r+1)=S_n(r)+\binom{n+r+1}{r+1}=\binom{n+r+1}{r}+\binom{n+r+1}{r+1}\stackrel{?}{=}\binom{n+r+2}{r+1}.$$

Comment: We are actually not allowed to use mathematical induction to solve this question.

Comment: That is why I have been stuck for hours simply trying to find a way to begin my answer!

Comment: @J.Khelly See my edited answer and fill the gaps.

Comment: That's still induction, though...

Comment: Yeah, but it was very generous of him to take the time out of his day and guide me in the right direction.